# Fabric not sending crash mail from last few days

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am not getting crash mail from last few days. below is my code

In my **Application class**

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

In **manifest**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="**********e17cbb0****6d2241b44**********" />
```

In **gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue buddy.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that I am getting JIRA tickets but no Crashlytics notification (so haven't worried about it).
Check your Crashlytics Notifications, I now have "New Issue" switched off.

Comment: It is showing crash on dashboard but not sending mail.

Comment: I have turn on all the notifications "new issue" and "new note" but still not getting the crash mail.

Comment: did u get any solution..to this. if you get any please post that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Emails are not sent on each crash report (that would overwhelm many developers). An email is sent when a brand new issue happens or daily using the stability digest.

If you're not seeing an email, I'd recommend creating a new type of issue and then see if you get the email.

Comment: Thank for your response Mike, If I mark crash as resolved from dashboard and if same crash happen again, will i get the crash report?

Comment: You would get the crash report, but you wouldn't be notified. If you close the issue and it happens in a different version, then if you have the "Regressed Issue" notification enabled, you would get an email.

Comment: whats the mean of stability digest. i also got this type of issue mail but not understood properly

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi can you clarify what's unclear or what you don't understand?

Comment: @Mike bonnell actually iam not understood the meaning of stability digest .....and when it occur ?

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell I am not getting any email notifications for any crashes, while it does show at the dashboard the number of crashes. Pl help. Thanks

Comment: Please contact support(at)fabric(dot)io if you have tried the steps above.